# how to select Custom column in spring jpa Repo

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}




public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {


    @Query(value = "select id from student", nativeQuery = true)
    Student findCostum();
}



@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpatestingApplication.class}, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@Profile("default")
public class JpatestingApplicationTests {


    @Autowired
    StudentRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        Student st = repo.findCostum();
        System.out.println(st);
        /*Student st = new Student();
        st.setName("nabeel");
        repo.save(st);*/
    }

}
```

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'name' not found.    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1077)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5174)   at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)     ... 72 more

Comment: Ok!! You gonna get downvoted a lot, mate! Why don't you start by asking us something, instead of spitting out code and stacktrace! Make some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe we'll start thinking of helping you.

Comment: why everybody want to native queries in JPA projects? Native query have not 'name' column

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
@Query(value = "select id from student", nativeQuery = true)
Student findCostum();
```

Doesn't make any sense. The query select id from student would return a list of Longs (the ids for all the students) not a single Student itself. Hence it complains the name column is missing because only one column is returned in this query and that is the id. Changing this to:

```
@Query(value = "select id from student", nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> findCostum();
```

will fix your error but I'm not convinced that is what you wanted to do at all. I assume you just want to find a given Student by their id? In that case you can just use the getOne(id) method in JpaRepository https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-

```
Student st = repo.getOne(id);
```